# Почему выдает такую ошибку ,если есть же слева customers?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: SQL state: 42P01]

ERROR: ОШИБКА:  отношение "customers" не существует
LINE 2: FROM customers
^

SQL state: 42P01
Character: 15

Comment: возможно нужно так `select * from public.customers`

Comment: Или опечатка (например, первая буква в имени таблицы - кириллица), или проблемы с правами, или ещё какая экзотика...

Comment: может окно запроса создана от другой базы, где нет таблицы customers

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы подключены к другой БД или другой схеме подключены.Еще есть вариант что у вас **с** кириллицей написано-опечатка,так сказать.
Попробуйте установить для работы с БД  DBeaver он удобнее.

Из документации:
Первая схема в пути поиска называется текущей. Эта схема будет использоваться не только при поиске, но и при создании объектов — она будет включать таблицы, созданные командой CREATE TABLE без указания схемы.

Чтобы узнать текущий тип поиска, выполните следующую команду:

SHOW search_path;
В конфигурации по умолчанию она возвращает:

### search_path

"$user", public
Первый элемент ссылается на схему с именем текущего пользователя. Если такой схемы не существует, ссылка на неё игнорируется. Второй элемент ссылается на схему public.

Первая существующая схема в пути поиска также считается схемой по умолчанию для новых объектов. Именно поэтому по умолчанию объекты создаются в схеме public. При указании неполной ссылки на объект в любом контексте (при модификации таблиц, изменении данных или в запросах) система просматривает путь поиска, пока не найдёт соответствующий объект. Таким образом, в конфигурации по умолчанию неполные имена могут относиться только к объектам в схеме public.

Чтобы добавить в путь нашу новую схему, мы выполняем:

SET search_path TO myschema,public;
(Мы опускаем компонент $user, так как здесь в нём нет необходимости.) Теперь мы можем обращаться к таблице без указания схемы:

DROP TABLE mytable;
И так как myschema — первый элемент в пути, новые объекты будут по умолчанию создаваться в этой схеме.

Мы можем также написать:

SET search_path TO myschema;
Тогда мы больше не сможем обращаться к схеме public, не написав полное имя объекта. Единственное, что отличает схему public от других, это то, что она существует по умолчанию, хотя её так же можно удалить.